What is the JSDoc's equivelant of 'extends' in Typescript
I am trying to extend type definitions @typedef in JSDoc. Coming from Typescript I am looking for something along the lines of extending interfaces like the code below.
interface Animal {
  name: string;
}

interface Cat extends Animal {
  color: string;
}

I have already tried to use @extends and @augments, like in the code below but with no luck. I think this can only applied to classes (as the error suggests) but not in types.
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Animal
 * @property {string} name - The animal's name.
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Cat
 * @extends Animal
 * @property {string} color - The cat's color.
 */

With this I am receiving the follow error
"JSDoc '@extends' is not attached to a class.ts", as this is expected to work only with classes.

Does this answer your question? How to extend a typedef parameter in JSDOC?
